# How to use the Ace editor validator without instantiating an Ace editor instance?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ace-editor, react-ace

I use `react-ace` to create a CSS text editor in my React app.

That looks something like...

```
import Ace from 'react-ace'

...
  <Ace 
    mode="css" 
    value={value} 
    onChange={onValueChange} 
    onValidate={onValidate} 
    ...
  />
...
```

This works fine and dandy—highlighting CSS syntax errors and warnings. Also, the `onValidate` returns the error/warning "annotations" data structure.

However there is a need, elsewhere in the application, to run the same validator used in this React Ace component, but outside of the context of this Component. Essentially I need to pass the content in `value` through the error/warning annotation system, but can't instantiate this react element.

I've tried the following:

```
import { EditSession } from 'brace'; # "brace" is the "module" compatible version of the ace editor that our "react-ace" uses
import 'brace/mode/css';

export const getCssAnnotations = (value)=> {
  const editSession = new EditSession(value);
  editSession.setMode('ace/mode/css');
  const annotations = editSession.getAnnotations();
  return annotations;
};
```

However, the annotations returned by this function are always `[]`! I assume this is because I'm just *accessing* the annotation setter/getter interface, and not actually running the annotations creator. But I can't figure out what actually does the annotations work normally.

I've looked at docs on [Creating a Syntax Highlighter for Ace](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=higlighter&api=document), but don't understand if/why a web worker would need to be involved here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't work, because editSession uses web worker to generate annotations which is async:

```
editSession.on('changeAnnotation', () => {
    let annotations = editSession.getAnnotations();
    callback(null, annotations)
});
```

[docs](https://ace.c9.io/api/edit_session.html#EditSession.event.changeAnnotation)

Note that currently each editSession creates a new worker, so it is better to use setValue on an existing instance of editSession, or call editSession.destroy()  before calling the callback

---

So a full solution might look like:

```
const getAnnotationsPromise = (value, mode)=> {
  const editSession = new EditSession(value);
  editSession.setMode(`ace/mode/${mode}`);

  return new Promise((resolve)=> {
    editSession.on('changeAnnotation', () => {
      const annotations = editSession.getAnnotations();
      editSession.removeAllListeners('changeAnnotation');
      editSession.destroy();
      resolve(annotations);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Awesome! That was exactly what I needed—thanks so much!